# automapper map dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, dictionary, automapper

I am working with Automapper and need to achieve the following mapping but not sure how it can be done.

I want to map a Dictionary object to a dynamic object, so that the key is the property on the object and the value of the dictionary is the value of property in dynamic object.

Can this be achieve with automapper and if so, how?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need the object to be dynamic, in this situation? As I see it the dictionary would be of type `Dictionary<PropertyInfo, object>`.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply get `Dictionary` from `ExpandoObject` and fill it with original dictionary values

```
void Main()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, dynamic>()
                     .ConstructUsing(CreateDynamicFromDictionary);

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dictionary.Add("Name", "Ilya");

    dynamic dyn = Mapper.Map<dynamic>(dictionary);

    Console.WriteLine (dyn.Name);//prints Ilya
}

public dynamic CreateDynamicFromDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
{
    dynamic dyn = new ExpandoObject();
    var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;

    dictionary.ToList()
              .ForEach(keyValue => expandoDic.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value));
    return dyn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's en example, but if you drop a comment or elaborate your post it could be more descriptive. Given this class:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int bar, string baz)
    {
        Bar = bar;
        Baz = baz;
    }

    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a dictionary of its public instance properties and values this way:

```
var valuesByProperty = foo.GetType().
     GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
     ToDictionary(p => p, p => p.GetValue(foo));
```

If you want to include more or different results, specify different `BindingFlags` in the `GetProperties` method. If this doesn't answer your question, please leave a comment.

Alternatively, assuming you're working with a dynamic object and anonymous types, the approach is similar. The following example, clearly, doesn't require the class `Foo`.

```
dynamic foo = new {Bar = 42, Baz = "baz"};
Type fooType = foo.GetType();
var valuesByProperty = fooType.
    GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
    ToDictionary(p => p, p => p.GetValue(foo));
```