# Automatically generating poco classes

Tags: orm, poco, t4

Today I was checking out a few technologies: [T4 templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

some mini orms: [petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), [sqlfu](https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu), [ormlite](https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite)

I understand the gist of what these technologies provide. I'm currently working on a 3 tier system, and I would have loved to replace the DAL (data access layer located on it's own data server) and have it integrated with a mini ORM as shown. However, I will be making no such plans for now. We currently use .NET Remoting (predates WCF).

So instead of replacing whatever is on the DataServer, I'd like to extend one of these new technologies on the application server.

I've done research on how Entity Framework can automatically generate POCO classes based on the context, which is done manually after building EF, I was wondering if I can do the same without using EF.

So here's the facts on what's currently happening:

1. Send a sql statement (or stored proc) to the DAL to execute
2. Retrieves a DataSet or a DataTable back to the application through TCP channel

My question is, is it possible to automatically generate a dynamic POCO class using keywords "var" and "dynamic" based on the values sent back from the DataSet and do dynamic mapping onto it during runtime? Would any of the technologies mentioned above help? Or do I have to manually create the POCO class first, and do a mapping on it?

It seems a bit redundant for me to manually create a POCO class and map it to a backend sql table if the application could be aware of what the POCO class is supposed to have. Like what happens if I update a table on the backend, then I'd have to update the POCO class associated with it as well. I'd love to have this to be automatic for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you know the data sets *at compile time*, then T4 might be an option.  You can write a T4 script that downloads the database schema, and constructs strongly-typed entity classes and database reads/write methods.
2. As far late-bound (runtime) classes, one option is to use the runtime typing provided by `CustomTypeDescriptor`.  You can pass arrays of objects back and forth from the server, and use reflection or other techniques to infer the type.

I think it should be clear that #1 is preferable, if you know the types at compile time (which it sounds like in your case here).  Runtime and dynamic should only be a last resort, as it circumvents a lot of valuable compile-time type checks.

Really, I would recommend using one of the micro ORMs like [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), etc, if you don't want to use the full Entity Framework.  That is, unless you really want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for this, I looked up CustomTypeDescriptor, very useful tool. Just wondering though, if I knew the datasets at compile time, why couldn't I just create a POCO class manually? I understand that T4 is great when you are coding things at design time, where changing one aspect of code will automatically change the aspect of another during compilation, but in my case, I'm getting a dataset at runtime returned from a dataserver. So option 2 would be my best bet.

Comment: Btw, I found a very very neat concept using System.Dynamic.DynamicObject, which I can create a POCO class that can inherit this, and in run time, bind any properties returned that didn't already exist before.

Comment: Actually, found out that automapper does have functionality and can use an ExpandoObject that allows me to do the mapping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329356/automapper-map-dynamic-object

Comment: Marking as answer since it helped me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: @sksallaj good stuff -- I completely forgot about `ExpandoObject`.  I'm working mostly with Silverlight, which of course does not have it.  I also forgot that you can use T4 at runtime, although that seems like it would be a hassle, at least in this case.

Comment: Eeek, I had my troubles with it too. I did find a library called Slapper.Automapper, which actually works well with ExpandoObjects. I created a dynamic object, and it was able to map all the properties to it. Very useful. http://randyburden.com/Slapper.AutoMapper/ , the automapper I mentioned works with expandoobject to a degree, but not fully supported.